# I am developing a quiz app accessible only at given time interval, everyday

Tags: android

I am developing a quiz app, which is accessible only at a given time interval every day.(say 10:00:00 am to 10:00:30 - 30 seconds)
The quiz should be open for users only at the specified time.
During other times, if a user opens the app it should only show a count-down timer for the next quiz.

Comment: HI, Please have a server which response makes the App enable/disable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hello Prudhvi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying to accomplish and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

see this example code for check the current time is between 10:00:00 and 10:00:30:

```
try {

            Calendar calendarCurrent = Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar calendarBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarBefore.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // add second
            calendarBefore.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // add minute
            calendarBefore.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10); // add hour 0-24

            Calendar calendarAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarAfter.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
            calendarAfter.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendarAfter.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);

            Log.e("current", calendarCurrent.getTime().toString());
            Log.e("after", calendarCurrent.getTime().toString());
            Log.e("before", calendarCurrent.getTime().toString());

            if (calendarCurrent.compareTo(calendarBefore) > 0 && calendarCurrent.compareTo(calendarAfter) < 0) {
                //checkes the current time is between 10:00:00 and 10:00:30.
                // run your function
                Log.e("ok", "ok");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and for count down timer you can use this code:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Log.e("your timer", "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }

}.start();
```

`best way and safe way and correct way you need server api` and set specific start and end time and then your application check it every moment for start quiz.

Comment: Don't do this. Don't use Calendar, use Java.time. Second, don't use use a countdown timer, if your app is killed, the timer is killed (and will be restarted). You didn't mention but if your app is not used the rest of the time, it will be killed. (even if it were used 24/7, you still shouldn't use a countdownTimer). Use WorkManager, or AlarmManager, schedule a JobIntentService to check your backend, and decide in the server, unless your want your quiz to be hacked in 5 minutes.

Comment: i know man, this is example, i mention he should use server api for checking start or end quiz, this is just client checking and not safe, i know, and thanks for your comment

Comment: No problem, but I really don't think this is a good answer. If anything, why don't you update it to use Java.time?